# How to design the layout using relative layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

In my android application I want to design the layout like blow

[image: home]

I have the four separate images like below

[image][image]

please anyone help me in this how to design this layout. Thanks in advance

Comment: Can't you use single image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this..

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/image1" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/image2" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/image4" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/image3" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:padding="5dp"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.25">
        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.75">
        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: working fine but the space between the images are very large how to reduce that

Comment: You can use single image as a background and to handle onclick of each 4 items you can use this layout as transparent view.

Comment: @ Rajiv Ratan I want to set animation for each imageview at the time of click

Comment: I just posted as answer for this because I was not able to attach picture here. It may help you.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you need to have 5 set of image. One is default and other four will be like [image]

So onclick of the image you need to switch the image with animation.